# Set color and boxes on conditions from data set (boxplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So I have a dataset called Carbon (Carbon$Graphite does contain a few values not seen in the head):

```
       Mesa  TIC   TOC Graphite    TC
Kx V17   Ja 5.26 15.64       NA 20.90
Mu V17  Nej 4.08 11.32       NA 15.40
Ob V17  Nej 5.22 12.68       NA 17.90
Vä V17   Ja 6.45  6.35       NA 12.80
Ös V17  Nej 3.90  2.54       NA  6.44
Ig V17   Ja 8.20  3.20       NA 11.40
```

I would like a boxplot that displays 8 boxes, one box that only contains values that fufills Carbon$TIC[Carbon$Mesa=="Ja, ], one that equals Carbon$TIC[Carbon$Mesa=="Ja, ], one that equals Carbon$TOC[Carbon$Mesa=="Ja, ] and so fort. And the colour (fill) of the boxes is Carbon$Mesa so "Ja"=red box and "Nej"=blue box. I have managed to do this without using ggpplot, but I need to do this with ggplot (so all my graphs look the same and the rest of the graps are done with ggplot).

The code I used to make it without ggplot (this is what I want but with legend on the side as usual for ggplot):

```
MesaJa <-Carbon[Carbon$Mesa=="Ja", ]
MesaNej <-Carbon[Carbon$Mesa=="Nej", ]

col.box<- c( rep("red", 3),   rep("blue", 3))

boxplot( list(MesaJa [, "TIC"], MesaJa [, "TOC"], MesaJa [, "TC"], 
              MesaNej[, "TIC"], MesaNej[, "TOC"], MesaNej[, "TC"] ),
         names=c("TIC", "TOC", "TC","TIC", "TOC", "TC") , 
         col=col.box
)  
legend("topleft", legend= c("Lime mud", "No lime mud"), pch=19, col=c("red","blue"), cex=0.7)
```

I have tried several different approaches but still not got it to work. The closest I got was this:

```
Carbon$TIC_Ja <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Ja",Carbon$TIC, NA)
Carbon$TIC_Nej <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Nej",Carbon$TIC, NA)
Carbon$TOC_Ja <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Ja",Carbon$TOC, NA)
Carbon$TOC_Nej <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Nej",Carbon$TOC, NA)
Carbon$TC_Ja <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Ja",Carbon$TC, NA)
Carbon$TC_Nej <- ifelse(Carbon$Mesa=="Nej",Carbon$TC, NA)

Carbon.plot<-Carbon[ , c(1, 6:11)]
Carbon.key <- colnames(Carbon)  

ggplot(
  gather(Carbon.plot, key=Carbon.key, value="value", -"Mesa"),
  aes(x=factor(Carbon.key), y=as.numeric(value), fill= Carbon.key) 
  ) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue"),
                    labels=c("Lime mud added", "No lime mud")
                    )
```

But it is still not good as I only want the upper two post in the legend and want to remove the "NA". And I think that there must be an easier way that does not involve using ifelse to sort the data frame. I have scoured SO but so far have not seen any example that is similar. So, please help?

Edit: added info on the df and session info. But After posting the question I started to update some packages and well, things did not go well so currently I dont even have ggplot working.

```
> str(Carbon)
'data.frame':   70 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Mesa    : chr  "Ja" "Nej" "Nej" "Ja" ...
 $ TIC     : num  5.26 4.08 5.22 6.45 3.9 ...
 $ TOC     : num  15.64 11.32 12.68 6.35 2.54 ...
 $ Graphite: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ TC      : num  20.9 15.4 17.9 12.8 6.44 11.4 12.9 21.6 11.8 15.3 ...

> dput(Carbon)
structure(list(Mesa = c("Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Nej", "Ja", 
"Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", 
"Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", 
"Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", 
"Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", 
"Ja", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", 
"Ja", "Ja", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", 
"Nej", "Nej", "Nej", "Ja"), TIC = c(5.26, 4.08, 5.22, 6.45, 3.9, 
8.2, 10.67, 7.43, 9.55, 8.19, 7.83, 4.04, 2.66, 4.93, 7.41, 3.25, 
4.47, 4.385, 3.48, 8.01, 9.49, 8.93, 6.03, 7.32, 3.84, 2.42, 
5.01, 3.87, 7, 4.8, 5.64, 5.76, 5.69, 8.7, 10.2, 9.78, 6.1, 8.07, 
4.33, 3.98, 7.39, 9.68, 9.67, 3.75, 5.07, 4.7, 4.86, 2.98, 8.05, 
10.29, 9.99, 6.65, 8.85, 4.82, 3.84, 8.49, 3.86, 6.63, 3.49, 
3.01, 4.83, 3.78, 8.95, 10.1, 8.15, 6.16, 8.15, 4.27, 3.96, 4.96
), TOC = c(15.64, 11.32, 12.68, 6.35, 2.54, 3.2, 2.23, 14.17, 
2.25, 7.11, 2.37, 17.16, 36.14, 13.47, 5.29, 17.95, 14.63, 3.85, 
6.31, 3.19, 2.81, 7.27, 23.07, 1.94, 26.19, 36.63, 23.19, 11.37, 
5.1, 2.39, 18.46, 2.17, 2.45, 1.7, 4.2, 4.92, 20.2, 0.86, 20.67, 
33.32, 5.11, 2.01, 0.53, 6.48, 29.51, 2.5, 9.41, 3.42, 3.04, 
4, 4.1, 11.15, 1.94, 20.66, 31.73, 1.81, 16.39, 20.75, 6.61, 
33.98, 2.48, 3.15, 1.65, 2.4, 12.63, 17.33, 0.99, 25.62, 38.63, 
17.93), Graphite = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.07, 
0.05, NA, 0.06, NA, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.07, 0.02, 0.08, 0.03, 0.33, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.02, 0.13, NA, 0.05, 0.02, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), TC = c(20.9, 15.4, 17.9, 12.8, 6.44, 11.4, 12.9, 
21.6, 11.8, 15.3, 10.2, 21.2, 38.8, 18.4, 12.7, 21.2, 19.1, 8.235, 
9.92, 11.2, 12.3, 16.2, 29.1, 9.26, 30.1, 39.1, 28.2, 15.3, 12.1, 
7.22, 24.1, 7.93, 8.14, 10.4, 14.4, 14.7, 26.3, 8.93, 25, 37.3, 
12.5, 11.7, 10.2, 10.3, 34.6, 7.28, 14.3, 6.73, 11.1, 14.3, 14.1, 
17.8, 10.8, 25.5, 35.7, 10.3, 20.3, 27.4, 10.1, 37, 7.33, 6.93, 
10.6, 12.5, 20.8, 23.5, 9.14, 29.9, 42.6, 22.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Kx V17", 
"Mu V17", "Ob V17", "Vä V17", "Ös V17", "Ig V17", "Va V17", "Gä V17", 
"Sk V17", "Fr V17", "Gr V17", "Bi V17", "As V17", "Kx H17", "Pi H17", 
"Mu H17", "Ob H17", "Do H17", "Ös H17", "Ig H17", "Va H17", "Gä H17", 
"Fr H17", "Gr H17", "Bi H17", "As H17", "So H17", "Kx V18", "Pi V18", 
"Mu V18", "Ob V18", "Do V18", "Ös V18", "Ig V18", "Va V18", "Gä V18", 
"Fr V18", "Gr V18", "Bi V18", "As V18", "So V18", "Kx H18", "Pi H18", 
"Mu H18", "Ob H18", "Do H18", "Vä H18", "Ös H18", "Ig H18", "Va H18", 
"Gä H18", "Fr H18", "Gr H18", "Bi H18", "As H18", "So H18", "Kx V19", 
"Pi V19", "Mu V19", "Ob V19", "Do V19", "Ös V19", "Ig V19", "Va V19", 
"Gä V19", "Fr V19", "Gr V19", "Bi V19", "As V19", "So V19"))

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] crayon_1.3.4     grid_3.5.3       R6_2.4.1         lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0    
 [6] magrittr_1.5     scales_1.1.0     rlang_0.4.5      rstudioapi_0.11  ellipsis_0.3.0  
[11] tools_3.5.3      glue_1.4.0       munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.5.3   colorspace_1.4-1
```

Comment: Can you provide a more reproducible example of your dataset ? (see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a possible way is to pivot your dataframe into a longer format using for example `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` (`pivot_longer` is available in `tidyr` `1.0.0`):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Carbon %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(TIC, TOC, TC), names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var,levels = c("TIC","TOC","TC"))) 

# A tibble: 210 x 4
   Mesa  Graphite var     val
   <chr>    <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
 1 Ja          NA TIC    5.26
 2 Ja          NA TOC   15.6 
 3 Ja          NA TC    20.9 
 4 Nej         NA TIC    4.08
 5 Nej         NA TOC   11.3 
 6 Nej         NA TC    15.4 
 7 Nej         NA TIC    5.22
 8 Nej         NA TOC   12.7 
 9 Nej         NA TC    17.9 
10 Ja          NA TIC    6.45
# … with 200 more rows
```

Then, you can use `interaction` to group "Mesa" and "var" as x values and get the following `boxplot` in `ggplot2`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

Carbon %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(TIC, TOC, TC), names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var,levels = c("TIC","TOC","TC"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = interaction(var, Mesa), y = val, fill = Mesa))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = rep(c("TIC","TOC","TC"),2))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue"), labels = c("Lime mud", "No lime mud"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I have been batteling this on and of for months before I finally gave up and asked for help :-)